# How do I check if webpage return 401?

Tags: angular, jwt

I was implementing a service and this service requires a JWT token to access.

When the JWT token expires below is shown on the page itself.

```
<oauth>
<error_description>
Access token expired: <token_value>
</error_description>
<error>invalid_token</error>
</oauth>
```

In angular all I am routing is

```
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent }
```

Example:

when I launch the page (locally - https://localhost:8080/)
I would get the token expired error. I wanted to capture the 401 as pageloads.

So how do I check if the current page is returning 401? For example, let's say if user refresh the page how do I get the 401 response instead of showing it in the webpage itself.

Comment: routing doesn't return 401 because it's client side. 401 is a server-side response for "unauthorized request". so odds are something in your code goes to the server and fails to access a resource. if you want to globally catch http requests and handle them at one place, you can use Interceptors. read the docs.

Comment: 4XX codes are generally the client ding something that the server does not expect. If you are able to verify that the page actually returns a 401, you can use an interceptor to check the status. see something like this for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47842939/angular5-http-reponse-interceptor-unable-to-read-status-code

Comment: The issue right now is that I dont know where this above request is made. I route to the page and the token is attached in cookie. I dont get the token explicitly and when page load when the token expires above error was shown.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand all the context, also its not clear if you can read from the cookie or not,if you can read the cookie, in HomeComponent you can maybe have a method to check if the token in the cookie is expired before you call the service that needs the token (so you wont get the 401 )

```
 import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie';
 @Component({
    selector: 'home-component',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
 })
 export class HomeComponent {
  tokenValid = true;
  constructor(public cookie: CookieService) {}

  ngOnInit(){
   this.tokenValid = this.isAccessTokenValid();
   if(this.tokenValid) {
     //call a service that uses the token
   }else {
     //do whatever
   }

  }

  isAccessTokenValid(): boolean {
   const acc_token = this.cookieService.get('token_in_cookie'); // use your key
   if (!!acc_token) {
     if (jwtService.isTokenExpired(acc_token)) {
       return false;
     }
     return true;
   } else {
   return false;
  }
 }

}
```

If what you need is just handle when the 401 from server, then you might need to implement and interceptor as suggested in the previous comments above, something like ...

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpRequestInteceptorError implements HttpInterceptor {

 constructor() { }

 intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

   return next.handle(req).pipe(catchError(err => {
     if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {

      // Token expired
      if (err.status === 401) {
        // refresh access_token or whatever
      }
    }
    return throwError(err);
  }));
 }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks but the intercept actually only intercept if the request is made after the starting page. My problem is that on the starting page it hits this 401 error.